# C++ API design - Should I pass enums as method parameters

Tags: c++, api, enum

I have two methods which are `GetMinimumSize()` and `GetMaximumSize()`. 
They return the maximum size of the window, and they take one parameter, which is an enum either `WindowSizeLimitParam::Width`, or `WindowSizeLimitParam::Height`, because of course, we want to specify which maximum or minimum we want to get.

Here is the enum

```
enum class WindowSizeLimitParam
{
    Width = 0,
    Height = 1
};
```

Some time ago, I didn't have this enum, and I just had 4 methods which were just for min size width, min size height, max size width, and max size height, but for the sake of shortness, I decided to do it with an enum.
So my question is, is this a good design choice? Using an enum to specify the size type which we want to get? Keep in mind I have other methods like setting size or getting size, but they don't use enums, they are `GetWidth()`, `GetHeight()`, `SetWidth()`, `SetHeight()`. If I'm using an enum for the size limit, should i use an enum here and just have `SetSize()` and `GetSize()` in which i pass an enum?

Is it generally a good idea to use enums if you are developing an API, which is kind of what I am doing here.

Comment: This question is lacking context, so it won't be possible to produce a sensible review. It sounds like you are asking about this more generally, as opposed to having a particular piece of code about which you are worried. If there is a particular instance you want reviewing, then we need to see how it is used (e.g. which method takes it as a parameter and how is it called). A more general query may be on-topic on the [Software Engineering StackExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to be consistent - if you already have `GetWidth`, `GetHeight`, `SetWidth` and `SetHeight` then it makes sense to have `GetMinimumWidth`, `GetMinimumHeight`, `GetMaximumWidth`, and `GetMaximumHeight`.

An alternative approach is to retrieve every value in a struct, which further simplifies your API surface and may improve performance if you expect a consumer to call most other getters:

```
struct WindowSizeInfo
{
    const int width, minWidth, maxWidth;
    const int height, minHeight, maxHeight;
}

WindowSizeInfo Window::GetSize()
{
    return WindowSizeInfo( ... );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It really is a better way of doing it when I give it a second thought